# The perfect tense of reflexive verbs

Tags: verbes, passé-composé, verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires

Why do reflexive  verbs form their perfect (*passé composé*) forms with "être". Does it have any historical reasons?

Comment: the same is true in Italian, but I don't think it's inherited from Latin. You might get better answers at linguistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: My intuition is that as reflexive verbs have their object as the subject, they came to use a form similar to passive, which uses "être" as well.

Comment: @Shautieh . C'est logique pour les verbes transitifs "pronominalisés", se laver, se rencontrer ... . Mais cela n'explique pas le cas des "vrais" verbes pronominaux: se souvenir de, se rendre compte - expression (mais j'ai rendu compte à ...)

Answer (score 4):

L'article de wikipedia est très complet : [Origine des auxiliaires être et avoir](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_auxiliaire#Origine_des_auxiliaires_.C3.AAtre_et_avoir).

A l'origine, le latin n'avait que le verbe *être* pour construire les temps composés. Par la suite, *avoir* est apparu dans les langues Romanes, d'abord dans certains cas, avec des verbes exprimant des opérations intellectuelles, puis s'est généralisé, dans des tournures avec COD, donc transitives.

Donc toutes les autres formes (dont les pronominales) ont gardé le verbe être.

L'article indique notamment quelques langues qui utilisent avoir comme auxiliaire de verbes pronominaux: Roumain, Catalan, Espagnol, Portugais.