# “Je me suis envoyé un mail” or “je m'ai envoyé un mail”?

Tags: participe-passé, pronoms-réfléchis

I try to say "I sent myself a mail". How do I say?

> Je me suis envoyé un mail.

or

> Je m'ai envoyé un mail.

Why?

Usually a verb that acts on the object itself would use "être", e.g.,

je me suis tordu le coud...

> j'ai senti <=/=> je me suis senti
>  il a tué <=/=> il s'est fait
> tué
>     je suis épaulé <=/=> j'ai épaulé
>  Tu es inquiété <=/=>
> tu as inquiété
>  Il a mangé <=/=> il est mangé
>  Nous avons
> marié <=/=> nous sommes mariés
>  Vous avez perdu <=/=> vous êtes
> perdus
>  J'aurai vaincu <=/=> je serai vaincu [...]
>
> **j'ai envoyé <=/=> je me suis envoyé**

but here the action is not "reflexive" (on the same object), but on another object (mail).

let's compare:

> J'ai été exigent avec moi-meme et je me suis envoyé au Brésil..
> Je me suis envoyé, je me suis donné, et les efforts paient.
>  Je me
> suis envoyé en l'air avec elle.

vs

> Je me suis envoyé une lettre...

Other cases:

> J'ai fait manger aux enfants. Je leur ai fait manger.

from where the confusion:

> J'ai envoyé une lettre à moi. Je me l'ai envoyé.

I mean there is a difference between "I sent something" and "I sent myself".
So I am searching for a grammar rule or something to understand this case...

---

Some explications found in [this article](http://jb.lelievre.free.fr/francais/contre-auxiliaire.html):

> On emploie en fait l'auxilaire *être* pour indiquer la passivité du
> sujet par rapport à l'action. On le retrouve donc dans la conjugaison
> des verbes pour lesquels le sujet subit l'action, de même que pour la
> voix passive des verbes pour lesquels le sujet produit l'action. Pour
> résumer, on distingue ainsi deux types de verbes : les verbes
> *d'action*, se conjuguant avec « *avoir* », et les verbes *d'état*, se
> conjuguant avec « *être* ».

Another example:

[image]

[link](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZlEJgJPUU1AC&lpg=PA166&ots=VFVF62AY6P&dq=je%20m%27ai%20fait%20mal&hl=fr&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q=je%20m%27ai%20fait%20mal&f=false)

> **Conclusion** *Je m'ai laissé me convaincre qu'une conclusion ne serait pas indispensable pour ce sujet.* :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The perfect tense of reflexive verbs](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16200/the-perfect-tense-of-reflexive-verbs)

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Your question is asking *why* pronominal verbs use "être" in the past tense. This question is (apparently) asking whether "être" is still used when the subject is not (semantically) acting on itself, even though grammatically it is. They don't look duplicate *at all* to me.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  l'explication est étymologique et grammaticale.c'est tout.

Comment: Me suis envoyé (sans e final), que ce soit un homme ou une femme qui le dise.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina I don't search historical reasons, I search a grammair rule for my exact case, as correctly noted Najib, la question n'a rien à voir une avec l'autre

Comment: "Je m'ai fait mal" is a joke, more precisely a mistake example here. A good hint is the title of the book from which this sentence is excerpted "La Grammaire des fautes."

Comment: "Il s'est fait tué". Shouldn't it be *il s'est fait tuer*?

Comment: J'ai fait manger *aux* enfants. --> "J'ai fait manger ***les*** enfants" ; Je *leur* ai fait manger --> "Je les ***ai*** fait manger" sinon "Je leur ai fait ***à*** manger" ou encore "Je leur ai fait manger *des pâtes*"

Comment: L'ajout sur les verbes d'action et les verbes d'état correspond à ma réponse formulée sans les mots des grammairiens, mais "another example" se réfère à un parler qui n'a plus court en France, ce parler était utilisé dans différents patois, surtout dans les campagnes, avant le chambardement des deux guerres mondiales.

Answer (score 4):

When you use a reflexive pronoun (i.e. when the direct object is also the subject), then you must use the pronominal form, regardless of the semantics. It doesn't matter that you're really acting on something else (the mail), grammatically the direct object is the subject; the subject is either acting on itself or in its own interest.

And in French, with "compound tenses" ([*temps composés*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_compos%C3%A9), I'm not sure what the translation is in English: passé composé, plus que parfait, passé antérieur...), you must use the auxiliary verb *être*. So the correct sentence is: **Je me suis envoyé un mail**. Wikipédia [gives a few more examples](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_pronominal):

> - Il se lave soigneusement (= il lave son corps)
> - Vous vous cultiverez en fréquentant les bibliothèques (= vous cultiverez votre esprit)
> - Elle s'est acheté un télescope (= elle l'a acheté pour elle-même)

The subject doesn't have to literally be acting on itself for the pronominal form to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Le verbe "s'envoyer" est un verbe réfléchi dans la mesure où l'action s'exerce sur le sujet.

"S'envoyer" veut dire "envoyer à soi-même", "se parler" veut dire "parler à soi-même."

L'action s'exerce sur le sujet donc l'auxiliaire ne peut être que le verbe être puisqu'il s'agit de verbe réfléchi.

Je me suis envoyé un courriel.

Comment: y a quand meme une difference entre "envoyer **à** soi-meme" (envoyer qqch) et "envoyer soi-meme" (s'envoyer)

Answer (score 2):

« *À la voix pronominale, l’être désigné par le sujet grammatical est à
la fois agent et patient, à la fois actif et passif.* » [(BDL)](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2939) L'intensité de l'apport du sujet à l'action, sa participation, varie et on distingue ainsi différents types d'emplois à la voix pronominale : [*réfléchi*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2954), [*réciproque*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2955), [*indistinct*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2956) et [*passif*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2957). Le *TLFi* note certains de ces emplois pour le verbe [*envoyer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envoyer) ; l'emploi pronominal *réfléchi indirect* pour l'aliment, la boisson, et par extension à la personne (*vulgaire*). *Larousse* note une difficulté et identifie de registre familier un emploi pronominal, [*s'envoyer qqc*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/envoyer/30174/difficulte), *absorber, devoir prendre en charge*. L'analyse du pronom n'est pas la même selon le type. Le *LBU* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14, §776-779) classe *s'envoyer* dans le sens qu'on vient d'expliquer comme un emploi subjectif (indistinct) se construisant avec un objet direct, familier, très familier ou même vulgaire. En emploi indistinct, normalement l'analyse du pronom ne révèle rien au delà de l'idée que le sujet est concerné par l'action autrement que comme agent uniquement. Cependant, *s'envoyer* est une exception dans cette catégorie, basé sur le modèle de *s'offrir* qqc., et le pronom s'y analyse clairement. Clairement mais pas nécessairement simplement, puisque le pronom pourrait renvoyer non à une construction introduite avec à, mais avec *pour* (LBU14 §672) par exemple (*je lui ai, je me suis, trouvé un emploi* = *pour* lui, *pour* moi). Le rôle du pronom dans cette catégorie est davantage [*fonctionnel*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2956) que grammatical/sémantique.

Dans le cas de l'emploi [réfléchi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2954), l'agent effectue l'action et la subit. L'analyse du pronom est celle d'un complément direct (*se laver*) ou indirect (*se nuire*) classique, dans ce dernier cas pouvant être accompagné par un objet direct distinct alors que le pronom est complément second (*je me coupe une tranche de jambon*). Il est intéressant de noter que quand l'emploi réfléchi et réciproque sont possibles à la fois, on use du pronom redondant pour distinguer les emplois (*Ils se lavent eux-mêmes* ; réfléchi).

---

La personne qui fait l'envoi est impliquée aussi comme patient, destinataire ici, qui ultimement le reçoit et c'est ce que l'emploi illustre à mon avis. Le courriel n'a pas besoin d'être le coude de la personne et l'action de s'y résumer à le tordre pour avoir un emploi pronominal ; un objet direct ne l'empêche pas. Un emploi familier de sens *indistinct* et différent n'empêche pas non plus l'existence d'un autre type d'emploi, comme *réfléchi*, ou un emploi entièrement non pronominal dans certains cas (préférablement quand le sujet n'est pas agent et patient à la fois ?). On l'a mentionné [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17744)([2](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17747)), aux temps composés on construit l'emploi pronominal avec le verbe *être*. L'analyse du rôle du pronom (*s'* pour *se* pour *lui*) dépasse dans certains cas le cadre de la grammaire traditionnelle.

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is :

> Je me suis envoyé un mail

Comment: why the second variant is not correct? we use "j'ai envoyé un mail"

Comment: Your reflection is correct but most of the french people will use the first sentence even if the second sentence is possible.

Comment: @CryZemo Are you saying "Je m'ai envoyé un mail" is correct ?

Comment: There should be a grammaire rule or something...

Comment: grammatically speaking yes, but no one use this sentence because 'je me suis envoyé' is phonetically better.

Comment: I added a PS to explain more in details..

Comment: @CryZemo In my opinion, "je m'ai envoyé un mail" is ungrammatical...

Answer (score 1):

The second form is very incorrect.

From the 1622 "*Nouvelle et parfaite grammaire française, où l'on trouve en bel ordre tout ce qui est du plus nécessaire, et du plus curieux pour la pureté, l'orthographe et la prononciation de cette langue*" by Chiflet:

[image]

In modern French:
*Tous les verbes pronominaux au passé composé se conjuguent avec l'auxiliaire être, et jamais avec avoir. Il faut donc dire au passé : « Je me suis trompé, Tu t'es trompé, Il s'est trompé, Nous nous sommes trompés, etc.» Et ceux, originaires de certaines provinces, qui disent « Je m'ai trompé, tu t'as trompé, il s'a trompé, nous nous avons trompé, vous vous avez trompé, etc. » parlent fort mal.*

Comment: The problem is if in my case I have a "verbe pronominal" or not...

Comment: It is definitively a pronominal verb. The subject performing the action is also the object of the action →"Je me"

Comment: can't really agree... the subject is me, but the object of the action is the mail... updated post with a link to article...

Comment: You are nitpicking. The subject is the one undergoing the action, he is sending a mail directed to himself. "Je" and "me" are the same person so the verb is definitely used with a pronominal voice.

Answer (score 1):

> Je *me suis* envoyé un mail.

... est la tournure usuelle pour dire : *J'ai **envoyé** un mél/courriel/e-mail/mail **à moi***.

> Je *m'ai* envoyé un mail.

Je *me* ai envoyé un mail :  l'apostrophe de **`m'`** remplace le **`e`** *me* et non pas l'`oi` de *moi*, la tournure usuelle serait faussée :

... *J'ai **envoyé** un mél/courriel/e-mail/mail **à me***.

Et même si l'on remplacer le *`m'`* par *moi* cela donnerait  *je **moi** ai envoyé un mail*, étant donné que *je* et *moi* sont la même personne, il faut supprimer l'un des deux sujets du verbe envoyer ; et  l'on traduit une action réflexive, qui impose le verbe être.

*Dans votre P.S. :*

- 1 - *Sentir* (perception olfactive ou de la sensibilité faite par quelqu'un) et *tuer* (action d'une personne sur une autre personne) touche à l'être, reflète la vie d'un être vivant.
- 2 - *Envoyer* est une action d'un être faite sur un objet,

Si l'objet (du 2) ne peut faire lui-même l'action en retour, un message n'envoie pas un message de lui-même, pour cela il faut un humain ou un programme pour le faire, l'action est faite à soi-même...  comme dans vos  deux premiers exemples (pour la partie à droite des `=>`).

Comment: ...you can say "j'ai senti une douleur", does not necessarily means olfactive sense...

Comment: Bien sûr, mais j'ai complété par : *ou de la sensibilité*. Cela renvoie au toucher où à d'autre sensations que les organes (excepté les yeux et la langue pour le goût [mais pas pour la texture des aliments]) envoient au cerveau à travers les terminaisons nerveuses