# Reflexive verb with avoir

Tags: grammaire, verbes, verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires, pronoms-réfléchis

I came across an expression "je m'ai engagé" and I want to know in what case(s) (if any), can *avoir* be used as auxiliary with reflexive verbs. Or this is probably a fixed expression?

Comment: Not really worth an answer, but that's something I've heard fairly often from some speakers in Belgium. Since Walloon and Picard exclusively use their equivalent of *avoir* as compound tense auxiliary, it's an aspect of their grammar that tends to be used in contexts where a Wallo-French mesolect is used rather than French, among family or in bars (Since it's a mesolect, other aspect of Walloon grammar are going to be used, so you're more likely to hear something like "Èdj' m'a engagé"). My grandmother sometimes slip into this usage in her French though.

Answer (score 9):

Si vous voyez un verbe réfléchi, comme « s'engager » et de nombreux autres, conjugué avec « avoir »,  **c'est une erreur.** Tous les verbes réfléchis utilisent « être » au passé composé, et la forme correcte est « je me suis engagé(e) ».

Comment: Good to know it's a mistake.

Answer (score 6):

The expression

> *Je m'ai engagé

is broken French. Only *Je me suis engagé* is correct.

It is then unlikely to be heard from native French people but might be found in books where it is used to exaggeratedly exhibit the ignorance, lack of education of some character (*je m'ai trompé* is a typical similar sentence sometimes used humorously), or the fact he is a foreigner lacking the French basic rule that says **pronominal verbs always use the *être* auxiliary**.

Here are some examples of intentional usage:

> *Qui vous vend ce polard ? Mon néditeur, non ?  Mézigue je m'ai engagé à rien, après tout.* San-Antonio, *Moi, vous me connaissez ?*
>
> [Parce que je m'ai trompé de compte :)](https://twitter.com/HMaler/status/753275533992099840)

See also https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17394/1109

---

Edit:

Now we know [what song this is about](http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/anathema/serenades.html), let's have a look to its multiple mistakes:

Song words:

> *J'ai fait une promesse
>
>   **La voie**, le saule s'incline **dessus du** ruisseau,
>
>   Comme une personne qui **se descend criant pour** l'amant.
>
>   Me rappelle **d'automne précédente**, en révérence,
>
>   Je m'**ai** engagé, je m'**ai** engagé, je m'**ai** engagé à vous*

Reverse translation:

> I made a promise (correct!)
>   The lane, the willow leans top the brook,
>   Like a person who is descending herself shouting for the lover,
>   Reminds me from the previous autumn, in reverence,
>   I is committing myself, I is committing myself, I is committing myself to you.

The intended meaning is:

> I made a promise
>   The way the willow leans over the brook
>   Like a person dropping down, crying for his lover
>   Reminds me of last autumn when, bowing down,
>   I pledged myself, I pledged myself, I pledged myself to you.

How it might have be written in French:

> *J'ai fait une promesse
>
>   La manière qu'a le saule pleureur de se courber au dessus du ruisseau,
>
>   Comme quelqu'un qui se penche, pleurant son amour,
>
>   Me rappelle l'automne dernier quand, m'inclinant,
>
>   Je me suis promis, je me suis promis, je me suis promis à toi.*

Given the "false friends" (*crier* for "to cry") and the "dictionary" translation mistakes (like *voie* for "way"), this translation was made either by someone with a very light level in French or by some machine translation software which, in 1993, were in a very early stage compared to what they are able to achieve these days.

Google translate does quite a decent job:

> *J'ai fait une promesse
>
>   La façon dont le saule se penche sur le ruisseau
>
>   Comme une personne qui tombe, qui pleure pour son amant
>
>   Cela me rappelle l’automne dernier quand, en s’inclinant,
>
>   Je me suis engagé, je me suis engagé, je me suis engagé à vous.*

Comment: I found the expression in the lyrics of a french song. Not sure whether the singer is native French but I believe so.

Comment: As I wrote, despite being immediately spotted as incorrect French by native people, it is nevertheless sometimes intentionally used for humorous purpose.

Comment: I found "je m'ai engagé" in Anathema's Serenades lyrics : http://www.darklyrics.com/lyrics/anathema/serenades.html but in that case, it is just broken French by a non native author. The whole song is barely intelligible and almost all sentences are broken.

Comment: That's the song I was referring to! I was trying to translate it into English but then it proved to be a difficult task. I'm glad to hear that it's not standard French.